# Is /var/crash/.lock safe to delete or should it be kept?

Tags: crash

Today when I booted Xubuntu 14.10, I was alerted that a "system program problem [was] detected".

This turned out to be `gnome-keyring-daemon`, since the file `/var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-keyring-daemon.0.crash` was created, and I have since deleted it.

Also in `/var/crash` is the empty file `.lock` which has these properties:

```
  File: ‘/var/crash/.lock’
  Size: 0           Blocks: 0          IO Block: 4096   regular empty     file
Device: 801h/2049d  Inode: 132494      Links: 1
Access: (0777/-rwxrwxrwx)  Uid: (    0/    root)   Gid: (  117/whoopsie)
Access: 2015-04-03 19:29:23.599839682 +0100
Modify: 2015-04-03 15:51:52.551215152 +0100
Change: 2015-04-03 15:51:52.551215152 +0100
 Birth: -
```

This file was modified and accessed at the same time as `/var/crash/_usr_bin_gnome-keyring-daemon.0.crash` was created, and it was then accessed a few hours later.

Why is this, and is it safe to delete, given that it's still being accessed?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I might as well answer this myself.

I've deleted `/var/crash/.lock` a few times now, with no ill effect.